# Python: Efficient way to search for string in stream

Tags: python

Given that stream is `aaa BOUNDARY bbbb BOUNDARY ...`, what I want is:

```
>>> read_until(stream, b' BOUNDARY ')
b'aaa'
>>> read_until(stream, b' BOUNDARY ')
b'bbbb'
```

The boundary is less than 100 bytes, the streamed data is infinite, coming with the rate of megabytes per second. The solution needs to be efficient in terms of memory and time, not naive peeking and reading from `BufferedReader`.

I'm looking for a short solution that, possibly, utilizes the standard library or widely used pure-Python packages. There are `email` and `cgi` libraries, which can read multipart chunks from a stream, which looks like what I need, but I couldn't understand how I can extract this functionality.

Alternatively, it would be nice to have something like the `BufferedReader` with a searchable buffer.

The last resort is to implement it by hand but it feels like inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This is the algorithm you need to use: [Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

I found this implementation online: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching-2/)

Comment: I'm happy to see a computationally effective algorithm, but it doubt that if it were implemented in Python, it would be fast in practice. I'm looking for solution that defer  the search operation to the level of compiled code.